# textbox accepts the following values in Javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a textbox and i need to validate that it accepts only 1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,...11.5
How to validate it.. pls tell the answer please.

```
 $(document).on('keyup', '#Dia_Inch', function (e) {
        Dia_Inch = $(this).val();


        if (Dia_Inch.charAt(1) == ".") {
            if (Dia_Inch.charAt(2) != "5") {
                this.value = '';
                $('#Dia_Inch').val("");
                alert("Number must be between 0 and 11.5 If zero inches, must enter 0 Enter 1/2 inches as .5; -Ex. 3 and 1/2 inches entered as 3.5");
                return false;
            }
        }

        var val = isNumberInch(e);
        if (val == false || Dia_Inch > 11.5) {
            this.value = '';
            $('#Dia_Inch').val("");
            alert("Number must be between 0 and 11.5 If zero inches, must enter 0 Enter 1/2 inches as .5; -Ex. 3 and 1/2 inches entered as 3.5");
            return false;
        }

    });
```

this my sample code.. but it wont be worked.

Comment: Why not use a drop down list box?

Comment: client requirement is textbox only @BillGregg

Comment: Exactly. A dropdown would solve this validation issue. You'll probably still need to validate but atleast that makes it more improbable that someone would enter a wrong value.

Comment: Would you be willing to use jquery?

Comment: ya no problem @JeevanJose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using jquery:

```
function validate(value){
  var arr = [1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,...11.5];
  if($.inArray(value, arr) >= 0){
    return true;
  }
return false;
}
```

You'll have to modify this according to your needs.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5Cm2w/

Do not forget to update the array with your actual values.

Comment: Where should validate() be called from?

Comment: @Jeevan Jose.. let me try urs

Comment: Validate should call on every keyup event @BillGregg

Comment: @BillGregg I've updated my answer. If you pass in the value, the function would return true or false based on whether the value could be found in the array or not.

Comment: Yikes, validating on every key up means that you are going to fuss at the user after they type "1." when they are about to type "1.5" which is a valid value.  As a user that would aggravate me.

Comment: @JasperManickaraj Check the updated answer. This should make it pretty easy.

Comment: @BillGregg The function would be called whenever you want to validate the input, be it keyUp, keyDown, userDance etc. :)

Answer (score 2):

This may solve your purpose.

```
$(function() {
    $('button').on('click', function() {
      var val = $.trim($('input[type="text"]').val());
        if(val.length && $.isNumeric(val) && val.match(/^\d+(\.5{0,1})?$/)) {
           alert('valid')
        } else {
            alert('invalid');
            $.trim( $('input[type="text"]').val('') );
        }
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ksxGj/1/)**

But if u want to allow up to 11.5 then

```
$(function() {
    $('button').on('click', function() {
      var val = $.trim($('input[type="text"]').val());
        if(val.length && $.isNumeric(val) && val.match(/^[1-9]{1}[1]{0,1}(\.5{0,1})?$/)) {
           alert('valid')
        } else {
            alert('invalid');
            $.trim( $('input[type="text"]').val('') );
        }
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ksxGj/2/)**

Comment: thecodeparadox just out of curiousity will the pattern /^[1-9]{1}[1]?(\.5?)?$/ work like yours?